# Как задать переменные для массива в момент его создания из другого массива?

Tags: php

Перекладываю один массив `$row` в другой `$services` и разбиваю по id для удобства в дальнейшей работе, так:

```
$services = [];
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($row["payment_service"] == 'PayPal'){

    $paypal_item_number = $row["id"];
    $paypal_amount = $row["amount"];
    $paypal_curr_code = $row["currency_code"];

    $services[$row["id"]] = $row;

   }
}
```

В первом массиве есть данные, которые нужно изменить, например, `["paypal_email"]=> string(16) "book@ya.ru"`, но мне нужно получить результат `["business"]=> string(16) "book@ya.ru"`.
Т.е. мне необходимо изменить часть названий, которые по умолчанию берутся из базы данных и не могут быть заранее в ней изменены.

Как в момент создания второго массива изменить названия?

Массив

```
array(8) {
 ["id"]=>
 string(2) "74"
 ["amount"]=>
 string(2) "10"
 ["currency_code"]=>
 string(3) "USD"
 ["validity"]=>
 string(2) "72"
 ["payment_service"]=>
 string(6) "PayPal"
 ["paypal_email"]=>
 string(16) "book@ya.ru"
 ["stripe_pkey"]=>
 string(0) ""
 ["status"]=>
 string(1) "1"
```

}...

Comment: с какой это стати не могут?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firstArray = [
    'paypal_email' => 'book@ya.ru', 
    'payment_service' => 'PayPal', 
    'currency_code' => 'USD'
];

$secondArray = $firstArray;
unset($secondArray['paypal_email']);
$secondArray['business'] = $firstArray['paypal_email'];
```

---

Так же можно воспользоваться `array_map`

```
$secondArray = array_map(function($item) {
    return array(
        'business' => $item['paypal_email'],
        'currency_code' => $item['currency_code'],
        // ... и т.д.
    );
}, $firstArray);
```

---

Ещё

```
$array = [ 'oldkey' => [ 'oldkey' => 'wow'] ];
$new_array = json_decode(str_replace('"oldkey":', '"newkey":', json_encode($array)));
```